# On mac os, how to remove a POSIX named semaphore in IPC with command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, posix, ipc, semaphore

I create some POSIX named semaphores in my program with `sem_open()`,

```c
sem_t semfoo = sem_open("/semfoo", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE, 10);
```

And remove it with `sem_unlink()`

```c
sem_unlink("/semfoo");
```

Sometimes when the program exit improperly, the `sem_unlink()` wasn't executed. So the semaphores still exist in shared memory. Then my next run will crash because of it. I have to create another `.c` file to unlink it manually.

I know there is `/dev/shm` in linux to check the semaphore stay in shared memory, but not for mac os. I also tried `ipcs -l`, but nothing listed,

```
T     ID     KEY        MODE       OWNER    GROUP
Message Queues:

T     ID     KEY        MODE       OWNER    GROUP
Shared Memory:

T     ID     KEY        MODE       OWNER    GROUP
Semaphores:
```

So is there some command line tools that I can use to check and remove the semaphores in shared memory on mac os, so that I don't need to create a new `.c` file to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an overkill, but I settled on a Python script based on https://github.com/osvenskan/posix_ipc:

```
import posix_ipc
posix_ipc.unlink_semaphore("/semfoo")
```